# numpy filter for not unique elements in 2d array

Tags: string, numpy, filter, 2d, unique

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
    [
        ['a' 'a'],
        ['a' 'b'],
        ['d' 'c'],
        ['a' 'b'],
        ['d' 'c'],
        ['a' 'a'],
        ['b' 'a'],
        ['c' nan]
    ]
)
```

How can i filter for the most frequent subarrays?
Expected results: [['a' 'a'], ['d' 'c']]

Comment: shouldn't the output be: ```[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['d', 'c']]``` ?

Comment: Or are measuring the frequency for columns?

Comment: i want frequency for columns: ['a', 'b'] != ['b', 'a']

Comment: ```data``` contains only 1 column. The strings are concatenated when creating the array.

Comment: u are right. there is one column and eight rows. my mistake. but the question is still the same.

Comment: In this case, the array is not homogeneous since the last row has only 1 column in. Numpy does not handle non-homogeneous arrays well and the expected speed will be equivalent with using normal python lists. However, you could add a null-character to the last row to make it  evenly spaced.

Comment: But to answer your question fundamentally, you can use [```np.unique```](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with ```return_count=True``` and select the returned rows which have the highest count.

Comment: it works perfectly for the array i gave you originally. However i made a second mistake i messed up the array, there is a nan too. i edited the original post. sorry it is my first question

Comment: i think i have to get rid of it it or change it to a null character

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand the question. Have a look at the answer I just posted and you can modify it for your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question, but I think `np.unqiue` might be useful.

```
data = np.array(
     [
         ['a', 'a'],
         ['a', 'b'],
         ['d', 'c'],
         ['a', 'b'],
         ['d', 'c'],
         ['a', 'a'],
         ['b', 'a'],
         ['c', np.nan]
     ]
 )

unique, idx, counts = np.unique(data[:,0], return_counts=True, return_index=True)
threshold = 1
data[idx[counts > threshold]]
```

Output:

```
array([['a', 'a'],
       ['d', 'c']], dtype='<U32')
```